# Turtles moving on a board game

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am currently creating Candyland in Python and I'm using turtles for the board. After the first turn the turtles are in a stopped position but on the second turn I created a ton of if statements for the turtles positions such as

```
if P1.pos() == y10:
    if draw2 == "Red":
        P1.goto(r11)
    if draw2 == "Red Red":
        P1.goto(r12)
    if draw2 == "Purple":
        P1.goto(p11)
    if draw2 == "Purple Purple":
        P1.goto(p12)
    if draw2 == "Yellow":
        P1.goto(y11)
    if draw2 == "Yellow Yellow":
        P1.goto(y12)
    if draw2 == "Blue":
        P1.goto(b10)
    if draw2 == "Blue Blue":
        P1.goto(b11)
    if draw2 == "Orange":
        P1.goto(o10)
    if draw2 == "Orange Orange":
        P1.goto(o11)
    if draw2 == "Green":
        P1.goto(g10)
    if draw2 == "Green Green":
        P1.goto(g11)
```

my issue is that the turtles now will go all the way to the end because there is an if statement like the one above for every space on the board. How do i make the turtles stop after one movement so that they don't end the game on the second turn.

Comment: You need to post more code as the problem isn't likely in this snippet. For starters, all but the first of these statements should be `elif`. Or even better, turn this long switch statement into a dictionary of moves or something to avoid laboriously typing out each possible if statement.

Comment: its ok I was able to fix it but thank you